# Linked List vs. Dynamic array for implementing a deck of cards? C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, linked-list, stack

Which would be better to implement something like a Magic the Gathering or Pokemon card game?
I have heard that linked lists are much faster and efficient for adding/removing cards from the deck; I have heard that dynamic arrays are faster for searching for specific cards however.

Do you know which is faster for shuffling?

So which do you think I should use to create a game such as the pokemon tcg http://hum1l1ation.hubpages.com/hub/PlayPoketcgDummy

Can I use both, or can a card deck simply be a stack?

So far my design is going to be a dynamic array of card classes within a deck class.

Comment: You measure the implementation with linked list against the implementation with dynamic array and you decide.

Comment: If you have only 50 or 100 cards (or only 1000) in a deck, both data structures will be so fast that you'll never notice a difference.  This is exactly the wrong kind of thing to optimize.

Comment: `std::deque` is probably the data structure of choice here, in fact.

Comment: @Brian: Incidentally, most `deque` implementations use a linked list of arrays.

Comment: Does order in the deck matter? Do you need random access? Basically, data structure selection is a huge and complicated topic. We can answer individual questions like "which is faster to shuffle" but it's much less clear which one should choose overall, simply because by the time you communicated all information that factors into that decision, you're beyond the scope of a question and it'd be "too localized" as well (since it becomes pretty much "solve this exact obscure problem for me please"). That said, when the choice is array versus linked list, `std::vector` is a good default.

Comment: It won't make any notable difference.  mem moves in the order of tens of megabytes are still very quick.  Unless you have millions of cards where each card is a big object, just use the structure that is the easiest to implement with and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance you won't probably see too much difference for a deck of less than 100 cards.

Also if you are using C++11, shuffling a vector is included in the standard library and it's very efficient:

```
void shuffle()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    auto seed = rd();
    std::mt19937 g(seed);
    std::shuffle(_deck.begin(), _deck.end(), g);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How many cards?  How big is each card entry?  Unless copying is
extremely expensive (and then, if you have C++11, you should be
able to use move semantics), `std::vector` will be the best
choice with regards to performance (not that it's likely to make
a significant difference for the user).  Most of the classical
big-O analysis has been invalidated by the fact that memory
access isn't constant time, but depends on locality; the less
total memory you use, the faster your code will run.  Today,
about the only reason to use `std::list` is the additional
guarantees it provides with regards to the validity of
iterators.

Comment: Of course, not every linked list is like `std::list`. An intrusive linked list usually has far better constant factors, can be more convenient, and doesn't require an expensive search for some operations. Also, "the less total memory you use" is not a good measure of locality. Of course less memory for the same algorithm slightly increases the odds of cache hits, but accessing the same amount of memory in a smarter order (i.e. optimizing for locality rather than size) often has a far greater effect.

Comment: Aw man, I love ya'll! I'm all exited to use vectors now! I didn't know std::deque existed. So motivational to have SO behind your back when you're working on code projects.

Comment: @delnan Locality is, of course, the real goal.  One of the simplest ways of improving locality is to reduce the number of allocations, putting logically adjacent elements adjacent in memory.  But of course, different programming techniques can affect it as well: binary search will have poorer locality than linear search (but in this case, the difference in big-O is enough to outweigh it), as will making three passes over a vector, when one would do.